# Create an Email Receive Event

Tags: windows, email, gmail, events

How can I create a Windows event to do somethings (i.e. open some programs) when I receive a GMail e-mail? I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Growler.

In addition to getting email notifications as a banner, you can have it kick off programs.

http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/

Answer (score 0):

Admin can develop and also handle several [**Event Management systems in PHP**](https://www.alphansotech.com/event-management-system-in-php) with this component. It includes the fundamentals parts such as budget planner, list, analytics, and extra.

- **Event Template**: Admin can develop custom motifs based upon the occasion objective utilizing our pre-built templates. It is additionally possible to leverage formerly produced event web pages.
- **Dashboard**: It will showcase the occasions together with their status, number of registered participants, and various other basic information.
- **Tasks**: Supervisors can designate jobs and their deadlines to the team and also monitor their performance. It guarantees that there are no slippages while finishing vital tasks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).